# MongoDB timeout under specific project only

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a 3 projects (.sln) that are their own project plus a secondary project that has the MongoDB code in it.

On the same computer with the 3 visual studio project open calling the same methods only 1 of them work the other all throw and error. Since it's the same line of code it mean there is a setting in the main project that mongo doesn't seems to like. Any idea what this might be.

here's the method in question in the shared project for mongo:

```
public static class MongoTool
{
    public static bool DoesCollectionExist(string username, string password, string uri, string port, string database, string collectionName)
    {
        // get the client
        var client = new MongoClient($@"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{uri}:{port}");

        // get the database
        var db = client.GetDatabase(database);

        // create the filter for collection names
        var filter = new BsonDocument("name", collectionName);
        var options = new ListCollectionNamesOptions { Filter = filter };

        // return if the filter return at least 1 record
        return db.ListCollectionNames(options).Any();
    }
}
```

in one of the project a dummy console application i have the following call and it works, it returns true.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1781
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = MongoTool.DoesCollectionExist("admin", "admin", "127.0.0.1", "27017", "SampleSet", "TemperatureProbe");
        }
    }   
}
```

In another project winform app i have this code (the third project use similar but have same error) :

```
private void CustomMongoSaveTest(Probe temperatureProbe)
{
    if (Environment.UserName.Contains("tech"))
    {
        // check if collection exist
        var collectionExist = MongoTool.DoesCollectionExist("admin", "admin", "127.0.0.1", "27017", "SampleSet", "TemperatureProbe");

        // if the collection exists
        if (collectionExist)
        {
            // create the bson document
            var bsonDoc = MongoTool.ConvertToBsonDocument(temperatureProbe);

            // insert in collection
            MongoTool.SaveDocument(bsonDoc, "admin", "admin", "127.0.0.1", "27017", "SampleSet", "TemperatureProbe");
        }

    }
}
```

Although being the same exact code running on the same computer that second one is throwing the following exception. Having the same project in attach to all solution i can easily follow the code and the exception occur on the line :

```
db.ListCollectionNames(options).Any();
```

With the exception being :

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
> CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
> : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{
> ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "127.0.0.1:27017" }", EndPoint:
> "127.0.0.1:27017", ReasonChanged: "ServerInitialDescription", State:
> "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
> LastHeartbeatTimestamp: null, LastUpdateTimestamp:
> "2020-08-07T16:00:54.4780565Z" }] }.

After adding extra methods for different handling like Collection Create/Delete, none of the works except when inside a console application. all project uses nuget `MongoDB.Driver 2.11.0`

I managed to check the difference in the log file when i run the line and it crash and this the difference in the Mongo logs :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:21:30.806-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn243","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60792","connectionCount":5}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:21:30.808-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn244","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60793","connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:21:30.808-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn247","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60796","connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:21:30.808-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn245","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60794","connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:21:31.951-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn246","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60795","connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:23:02.293-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn242","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60791","connectionCount":0}}
```

When calling the same line form the app that works the log is different, i have this :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.088-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61402","sessionId":248,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.093-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61403","sessionId":249,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.136-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn249","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61403","client":"conn249","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-csharp-driver","version":"2.11.0.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows","name":"Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362","architecture":"x86_64","version":"10.0.18362"},"platform":".NET Framework 4.8.4180.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.137-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn248","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61402","client":"conn248","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-csharp-driver","version":"2.11.0.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows","name":"Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362","architecture":"x86_64","version":"10.0.18362"},"platform":".NET Framework 4.8.4180.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.235-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61404","sessionId":250,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.244-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn250","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61404","client":"conn250","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-csharp-driver","version":"2.11.0.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows","name":"Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362","architecture":"x86_64","version":"10.0.18362"},"platform":".NET Framework 4.8.4180.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:02.297-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn250","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"127.0.0.1:61404"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:04.835-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn250","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61404","connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:04.835-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn248","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61402","connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:05.334-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4615610, "ctx":"conn249","msg":"Failed to check socket connectivity","attr":{"error":"The operation completed successfully."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:05.334-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn249","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":4183920}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:05.334-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22989,   "ctx":"conn249","msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Connection reset by peer"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:61403","connectionId":249}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-07T12:31:05.334-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn249","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:61403","connectionCount":0}}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm getting the same error under the same circumstance. What's even stranger is that the timeout error only occurs when the debugger is attached. Without the debugger attached it works fine.

Comment: I think i am onto something. I am currently going through all my libraries into my software and it seems that as long as i run the code in the program.cs it works but as soon as i run it anywhere else it fails. I have over 300 libraries to go through so it will take a while. My guess is that one of these libs use an older third party lib au cause some kind of culture / version error with MongoDB.Driver

Comment: I just downgraded my driver to 2.9.3 and the issue disappeared. I searched far and wide for for anyone else reporting this issue, and yours was the only other similar report, also with 2.11.0 suggested to me that this is a new issue intro in the latest version.

Comment: No timeout in 2.10.4 either, I'm only seeing this issue 2.11.0

Comment: @ChrisLukic i will try this asap

Comment: @ChrisLukic I found 1 of the library that if i load once then call `MongoDB.Driver` it fails non stop. If i call Mongo once then call that library and then recall mongo it still works. So it's definitely a versioning issue with libraries. Since i can replicate the code everytime now i tried downgrading to 2.10.4 and that version works flawlessly. I have already send to that third party company dll the issue i was having as they have their source code and can figure out the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is as of the time of writing this the `MongoDB.Driver v2.11.0` is bugged. There is some sort of incompatibility in the library it's using that if you downgrade to `MongoDB.Driver v2.10.4` it works perfectly.

Edit : It doesn't work "perfectly" as i described. Actually one major problem is that i cannot use allowDiskUse on any find operation anymore with 2.10.4. It doesn't seem to accept it or work at all.